# How react-native app listens gps as background service?

Tags: react-native

*I want to get location when even app is off.
Forexample; I go to shop. when distance between me and shop is below 5 meter, I want to get alert or popup notification "welcome to shop."*

*What should I use ? geolocation.watchposition or something else ?*

Answer (score 0):

You can try this npm: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-background-geolocation

Your use-case cannot be achieved from geolocation from react-native